# Can I use inline raw LaTeX in reStructuredText

Tags: latex, restructuredtext

I am trying to embed a LaTeX variable into some reStructuredText. I know about the ".. raw::" directive, but I want this to be embedded in a paragraph of text. Specifically, I am looking to replicate the \numquestions\ and \numpoints\ variables from the template exam document. I have tried using :raw:`\numquestions\`, but this does not seem to be valid. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `raw` role (the inline equivalent of the `raw` directive). See these references:

- http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#how-can-i-include-mathematical-equations-in-documents
- http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw