# LaTeX in RST processed with Pandoc

Tags: latex, restructuredtext, pandoc, pdflatex

I want to use ReStructuredText to take notes, and I sometimes want to add equations to the notes with LaTeX. I followed the advice of both answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533406/can-i-use-inline-raw-latex-in-restructuredtext) question, but neither of them worked for me. I have an RST file called `foo.rst` with these contents:

```
.. role:: latex(raw)
   :format: latex

==============
This is a test
==============

Test with latex role :latex:`\Delta X`

Test with raw role :raw:`\Delta X`

Test with raw role and $ :raw:`$\Delta X$`

Test with raw role and $ :raw:`$\Delta X$`
```

Then when I compile this to a pdf with `pandoc -o foo.pdf foo.rst`, I get this output.

[image: Imgur]

If I first compile to tex, I get this:

```
\section{This is a test}\label{this-is-a-test}

Test with latex role \textbackslash{}Delta X

Test with raw role \textbackslash{}Delta X

Test with raw role and \$ \$\textbackslash{}Delta X\$

Test with raw role and \$ \$\textbackslash{}Delta X\$
```

It seems to be escaping the text inside of the `raw` and `latex` directives. Is there a way to use inline LaTeX with pandoc and RST?

Comment: You might be more successful asking on the [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss) mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a [math directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#math) and a [math role](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#math) that should do the job:

```
The area of a circle is :math:`A_\text{c} = (\pi/4) d^2`.
```

Then:

```
pandoc -o foo.pdf foo.rst
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: That's nice to have, but what about other latex? In Pandoc Markdown you can inline arbitrary latex code and it will stay as it is, until it is pasted into the pandoc template, which is then compiled to PDF. Is this possible with reStructuredText as well?